# How to split and paste a string while mutating a dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe like this one:

```
x <- data.frame(filename = c("aa-b-c x", "c-dd-e y"), number=c(1,2))
  filename  number
1  aa-b-c x      1
2  c-dd-e y      2
```

I want to mutate the filename column so it looks like this:

```
  filename number
1  c/aa/b      1
2  e/dd/c      2
```

This works on a single row: `paste(str_match(x$filename[1], "(\\w+)-(\\w+)-(\\w+)")[c(4,2,3)], collapse = "/")` but it fails inside the `mutate`. I'm sure I'm missing a simple fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to rearrange the components after capturing as a group

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
x %>%
    mutate(filname  = str_replace(filename, 
         "^([a-z]+)-([a-z]+)-([a-z]+)\\s.*", "\\3/\\1/\\2"))
```

Answer (score 2):

`str_match` returns a matrix when you give it multiple vectors. This should work pretty well:

```
apply(str_match(x$filename, "(\\w+)-(\\w+)-(\\w+)")[, c(4,2,3), drop = FALSE], 1, paste, collapse = "/")
# [1] "c/aa/b" "e/c/dd"
```

The `drop = FALSE` is necessary to keep the output a matrix in case there is only one row.